# Possible to check upload progress from a different ActionResult?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible (and how) for an ActionResult to update a session variable (or any other store) so that I can asynchronously call a different actionResult and get the upload status?
I want to build a very simple uploader that will show a real progressbar.  I found several plugins on the web, but they are all overkill. I don't need to upload multiple files and I dont' want pause, resume, etc.
Just a single Jquery/MVC solution to upload a single file with a progress bar.  Anyone have code they can share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's not possible to create a different ActionResult to check a download status. You should look for HTML 5 upload and the `XMLHttpRequest` in JavaScript. Take a look at this tutorial: http://www.matlus.com/html5-file-upload-with-progress/

Comment: Thanks for the link - it was a little helpful.  The biggest problem I have with HTMl5 and the upload enhancements is that IE doesn't support it and that is my largest user base.  I'm hoping to make something like the jquery file upload plugin, but much more simplified.  Thanks Marth